# Using shipped version of jquery

Tags: php, jquery, javascript

Thare are no errors in the JS console. My goal is to use the shipped version of jQuery that Wordpress uses to work with bxslider. According the link shown [here](http://plugins.twinpictures.de/wordpress-jquery-versions/), the current version of jquery shipped with wordpress 4.0 is 1.11.1, the same version I'm using when I'm testing it by deregistering the default version. However, themeforest guidelines outline that "Authors are not allowed to deregister the default version of jQuery and load another one" and "Themes will be required to use whichever version of jQuery ships with the current version of WordPress." Is there a reason why one way works but not the other?

What I've already tried:
`wp_enqueue_script('jquery');`

`wp_register_script('gallery-script', MALEFICENT_PATH . '/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js', array('jquery'), null, true);`

What's happening is that the 3 images that I have in place are no longer displayed in a slider when I remove the deregister script and add the following above. What I have below works, but this involves deregistering the default jquery from Wordpress.

I currently have the following that **WORKS**:

```
function register_frontend_javascript()
{
// Deregister the included library
wp_deregister_script('jquery');

// Register the library again from Google's CDN
wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js', array(), '1.11.1', false);

// Register the script like this for a theme:
wp_register_script('gallery-script', MALEFICENT_PATH . '/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js', array(), null, true);
wp_register_script('main-script', MALEFICENT_PATH . '/js/main.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
wp_register_script('modernizer', MALEFICENT_PATH . '/js/modernizr.js', array(), null, false);
wp_register_script('foundation', MALEFICENT_PATH . '/js/foundation.min.js', array('jquery'), null, true);

// For either a plugin or a theme, you can then enqueue the script:
wp_enqueue_script(array('gallery-script', 'main-script', 'modernizer', 'foundation'));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_frontend_javascript');
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The problem is most likely in your main.js, not in bxslider. Make sure you use `jQuery`, not `$`, or that you use a proper noConflict wrapper.

Comment: Appreciate the reply! The problem was in fact in main.js. Problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery library packed with WordPress, operates under noConflict mode. Means you can not use `$` in your jQuery snippet/code. Either use `jQuery` instead of `$`.

or use noConflict wrapper like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        // your jquery function, you can use $ here.

    });
  // -->
</script>
```

Comment: My pleasure, glad it worked. Enjoy :-)